# Food warmed in a non-kosher microwave assur b'han'ah?

Tags: meat-and-milk

If someone warmed pareve food in a dirty microwave that has been used to cook basar b'chalav and there is remnants of that food in the microwave, or he warmed milchig or fleishig food in a dirty microwave that had been used to cook the opposite and there was remnants of it in the microwave, would the resulting food become assur b'han'ah?

Comment: probably only its taste

Comment: Do you know something about the 'regular' case of cooking pareve food in a pot that had been used for basar bechalav and are asking about a microwave specifically? If so please tell us what you know and why you think this may be different.

Comment: Its a big discussion if a microwave is considered bishul for basar bchalav and the prohibition of cooking on shabbas